# Logging into quora using python mechanize

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, xmlhttprequest, web-scraping, mechanize-python

I am trying to log into quora using mechanize module. Following is the code I am using:

```
import mechanize
import cookielib

br = mechanize.Browser() # create a browser object
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_headers = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)')]

cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

res = br.open('http://www.quora.com')
br.select_form(nr = 0)

br.form['email'] = 'uuuu'
br.form['password'] = 'pppp'

res = br.submit()
print res.read()
```

I am getting following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mech.py", line 29, in <module>
    res = br.submit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 541, in submit
    return self.open(self.click(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 203, in open
    return self._mech_open(url, data, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 255, in _mech_open
    raise response
mechanize._response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

One of the answer to the same question says that its because this particular form is submitted via  javascript XHR POST request to [https://www.quora.com/webnode2/server_call_POST?**instart**](https://www.quora.com/webnode2/server_call_POST?__instart__) where request parameters looks like:

```
json:{"args":[],"kwargs":{"email":"<email>","password":"<password>","passwordless":1}}
formkey:62c4f0d88246bfd81b27cf0dca410d75
window_id:dep4-4597603286175583039
_lm_transaction_id:0.4317954108119011
_lm_window_id:dep4-4597603286175583039
__vcon_json:["hmac","t1cKg1QhQsYPCA"]
__vcon_method:do_login
js_init:{}
```

Is there any module to solve this problem??

P.S. I used selenium, it works but its very slow.

Comment: Have you tried a headless browser with selenium (PhantomJS, for example)?

Comment: No I didnt try but will there be significant increase in speed?? Isnt there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: You should definitely try `PhantomJS` - it is as easy as changing `webdriver.Firefox` to `webdriver.PhantomJS` (you need to also download phantomjs driver, of course).

Comment: mechanize works for me with similar code except I just use: `br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]`